# How to bind an ASP.NET controller property with part of the current URL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using netcoreapp1.1 (aspnetcore 1.1.1).

I would like to bind a part of the url to a controller property and not in an action parameter, is it possible?

Ex:
GET: https://www.myserver.com/somevalue/users/1

```
public class UsersController {
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;} //receives "somevalue" here

    public void Index(int id){ 
        //id = 1
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with action filter:

```
[Route("{foo}/[controller]/{id?}")]
[SegmentFilter]
public class SegmentController : Controller
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
    }
}

public class SegmentFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //path is "/bar/segment/123"
        string path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;

        string[] segments = path.Split(new[]{"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //todo: extract an interface containing SomeProperty
        var controller = context.Controller as SegmentController;

        //find the required segment in any way you like
        controller.SomeProperty = segments.First();
    }
}
```

Then the request path `"myserver.com/bar/segment/123"` will set `SomeProperty` to `"bar"` before action `Index` is executed.